# Bootstrap CSS, what is the purpose of the "container" class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap, and in fact trying to retrofit a website that I didn't design myself. I'm trying to understand the purpose of the "container" class. Is there ever a case in which I would want no containers? How about two of them?

Comment: I think I have a great question, which in case you didn't notice asked if there was a case in which I would want no containers, and a case in which I would want two. I think answering this would create a good example that cuts through the noise and says something meaningful in a lot less jargon.

Answer (score 4):

Like always the [**docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) have the answer to such questions:

> **Containers**
>
> Easily center a page's contents by wrapping its contents in a
>   .container. Containers set max-width at various media query
>   breakpoints to match our grid system.

Taking a closer look at the css file, the container element has as set max-width pixel value:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 970px;
  }
```

While  `.col-` (span in v2) have their values set in percentages :

```
.col-md-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
```

Container classes serve as a reference, allowing bootstrap's responsive grid layout to function properly.

Comment: You are speaking tongue-in-cheek, I see. Because "containers set max-width at various media query breakpoints to match our grid system" -- a statement I noticed in the docs myself, and which is there adorned with no further explanation -- is not exactly self-explanatory.

Comment: @composerMike download the css file from bootstrap and navigate to line 805 in the unminified version, you will see media queries specific to the container class, now the span classes are set in percentages while the container's value is in pixels. Long story short, the `.container` class is what the percentages are based off.

Comment: I agree with @composerMike. Docs are just a quick reference without going further into details. You'll need to review the CSS file to know   more than specified in the Docs

Comment: @equisde Added a bit more info to the answer, thing is the answer is in the code, bootstrap's responsive power and grid depends on the container class.

Comment: Sorry little typo. I meant I agree with you @PatsyIssa and I was replying to composerMike  :-D

Comment: I'm not going to disagree that studying the manual and source code is helpful, and I won't press my point here, so don't worry about answering. But I just want to be very clear what my point is. I'm looking for an understanding of how and when `container` is **used**. I'm looking for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just to declare bootstrap's "fixed" of "fluid" flavors (container vs container-fluid).